# Running Rails Application on netbeans 6.7 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans6.7

i was upgrading my Netbeans 6.5 to Netbeans 6.7

and i open my rails application which built on Netbeans 6.5

and i run but it doesnt working ,  said :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jruby/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jruby.Main
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
Could not find the main class: org.jruby.Main.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"

what heppened??

and also i cant make new project rails with netbeans 6.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go into the plugins panel (menu is tools:plugins) and install the ruby plugin.

Comment: If the plugin were installed, you would be able to create new ruby projects.  Do you have the "Ruby Platforms" and "Gems" menus under the tools menu?  Can you provide a screenshot of your "installed plugins" screen?

Comment: ya i know that.. but there were ruby on rails has been installed at list

Answer (score 0):

I looks like Netbeans can't find the JRuby classes. Perhaps try pointing your Ruby platforms to the old JRuby directory? Just a guess as I don't use JRuby myself (although I use NB 6.5 and 6.7)